# "in that luxury" or "in the luxury"

Tags: word-usage

> The season of strikes seemed to have run itself to a standstill.
>   Almost every trade and industry and calling in which a dislocation
>   could possibly be engineered had indulged **in that luxury**. The last and
>   least successful convulsion had been the strike of the World's Union
>   of Zoological Garden attendants, who, pending the settlement of
>   certain demands, refused to minister further to the wants of the
>   animals committed to their charge or to allow any other keepers to
>   take their place.
>
> from [The Unkindest Blow](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/UnkiBlow802.shtml), a short story by Saki

What is the difference between "in that luxury" and "in the luxury"?

Comment: If it were *the* luxury, I would have to ask, "*What* luxury?" because nothing had yet been established. By using the demonstrative, you are figuratively *pointing* to the luxury you're talking about. (Striking, as mentioned in the previous sentence.) But you could say *the* luxury *of striking*, because the final words qualify it, isolating that particular luxury from the others.

Comment: I think "the" is also demonstrative.

Comment: I found several written instances of [We cannot afford the luxury of a strike,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22afford+the+luxury+of+a+strike%22) which just goes to show it's not a ridiculous reference.

Comment: @bandaid Grammatically speaking, it is not. *The* is a definite article—whereas *that* is a demonstrative pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

"*The* luxury" and "*that* luxury" have almost the same meaning: "a particular, specific instance of luxury."

"That" is a little more emphatic and indicates that the particular specific instance is the one which has just been specified. Because hearing of a strike as a "luxury" might not be expected by readers, the writer used "that" so it would be clear to his audience that striking was indeed what "luxury" referred to.

Comment: What does "luxury" refer to? I think it's odd to say "A strike has a luxury."

Comment: Yes, I think it's odd too. (See FumbleFingers' comment on the question.) Although I haven't read the whole story, it sounds to me like maybe Saki was using the word "luxury" (which sounds kind of ridiculous in this context) to subtly express his attitude either toward strikes in general, or else toward the completely degenerated situation he describes in the passage.

Answer (score 0):

He is implicitly referring to a strike as a luxury taken by the strikers or their unions. Since this is not an obvious reference, if he said "the luxury", it would be unclear whether he was referring to striking or to something else (perhaps something in a previous sentence). Using the demonstrative "that" makes it clear that he is referring back to what he has just said, and defining it as a luxury. (I suppose it is still potentially ambiguous, because "that" could have different antecedents; but in context it must be the strikes).